# Return spreaded array in arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's assume i have this type of array:

`[ [1, 2], [3, 4] ]`

What i need to do is to get nested elements on the higher layer, to make it look like:

`[1, 2, 3, 4]`

I am trying to reach that in functional way, so the code look's like this:

```
const arr = [ [1, 2], [3, 4] ]
const f = Array.from(arr, x => ...x)
```

But that comes up with `Unexpected token ...` error. So what's the way to do it right?

Comment: There’s [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat). Look at its [polyfills](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Alternative).

Comment: Will the nested elements always be Arrays?

Comment: Your confusion stems from the fact that the spread syntax is not an operator. It's a contextual syntax.

Comment: @Xufox thank's for that! `flat` seems pretty good to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `flat` method of Array:

```js
const inp = [ [1, 2], [3, 4] ];

console.log(inp.flat());
```

In your case, the spread syntax is not an operator that you can use in that way, that's why the error.

As @MarkMeyer correctly pointed out in the comments, the `flat` is not supported yet by Edge and Internet Explorer. In this case you could go for a solution with `reduce`:

```js
const inp = [[1,2], [3,4]];
console.log(inp.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(...val), []));
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning this does not (currently) work on Edge, Internet Explorer, or Node.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts which version are you using? it's working since chrome 69

Comment: @PatrickRoberts you can check the browser compatibility here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: chrome also supports `flatMap`

Comment: Oh, I had a flag set, that was my bad.

Answer (score 3):

`Array.from` will produce an item for every item in the array passed in. It looks at the `length` of the passed in iterable and iterates over the indexes starting at 0.  So no matter what you do in the callback (assuming it's valid), you're going to get an array of length 2 output if you pass in a two-element array.

`reduce()` is probably a better option here:

```js
let arr = [ [1, 2], [3, 4] ]

let flat = arr.reduce((arr, item) => [...arr, ...item])
console.log(flat)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an iterator for the array and spread the array by using another generator for nested arrays.

```js
function* flat() {
    for (var item of this.slice()) {
        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
            item[Symbol.iterator] = flat;
            yield* item
        } else {
            yield item;
        }
    }
}

var array = [[1, 2], [3, 4, [5, 6]]];

array[Symbol.iterator] = flat;

console.log([...array]);
```

Comment: That's pretty cool. It might be nicer if `flat()` took the array as a parameter and was called recursively so you avoid the side effect of altering the sub arrays. But then you'd have to call `[...flat(array)]`