# How can I iterate over nested arrays with recursion?

Tags: javascript, python

How can I iterate over nested arrays like this with recursion in javascript:

```
var a = [10, [1, [2,2,2], 3], 20, 'Hallo']
```

In Python it looks like this:

```
def foo1(L):
    for i in L:
        if not isinstance(i, list):
            print(i)
        else:
            foo1(i)

foo1(a)
```

How can I write `if not isinstance(i, list):` in javascript?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-an-array) look like a suitable dupe to you JS folks?

Comment: what is your expected output..

Comment: maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/q/45708712/1447675 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/53998384/1447675 helps ...

Comment: `if (!Array.isArray(item)){...}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```js
var a = [10, [1, [2,2,2], 3], 20, 'Hallo']

for (let item of a) {
    if (!Array.isArray(item)){
      console.log("Not array", item);
    }else{
      console.log("Array", item);
    }
}
```